# Why doesn't this code draw a square on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm having trouble understanding why my code won't draw a square border on the canvas.  I just started learning this stuff, and I'm afriad I'm missing something obvious...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
canvas {
    background-image: url(uploads/1504975677.jpg);
    width: 500px;
    height: 334px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javscript">
    var x = 100;
    var y = 100;
    var width = 50;
    var height = 50;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('image');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.strokeStyle = 'white';
    context.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
</script>
<title>Test Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="image"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

To clarify, I'm not trying to create a border for the canvas, I just want a box that is not filled in.  All I get with this code is the background image and nothing drawn on top of it.

Comment: also please remove misspelled type="text/javscript", is default for HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should be the format put your script before closing the body tag, Also change the color :-p

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    canvas {
      background-image: url(uploads/1504975677.jpg);
      width: 500px;
      height: 334px;
    }

  </style>
  <title>Test Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="image"></canvas>

  <script type="text/javscript">
    var x = 100; var y = 100; var width = 50; var height = 50; var canvas = document.getElementById('image'); var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); context.strokeStyle = 'black'; context.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
  var x = 100; var y = 100; var width = 50; var height = 50; var canvas = document.getElementById('image'); var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); context.strokeStyle = 'black'; context.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 334px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="image"></canvas>
```

Comment: Try to explain why this works and why the original code didn't.

Comment: The miss-spelling seems to be the only thing wrong.  Ty.